# Client side chart export library

Tags: charts

I'm looking for a client side (that is: HTML5, Javascript, Flash or Silvelight) library, which is

1. capable of creating interactive charts
2. capable of exporting these charts into jpg/png
3. is free (LGPL, or similar)

I have looked into Highcharts, and FusionCharts; both are very good choices - except that these can not be used in commercial software.

Are there any charting libraries with the above mentioned conditions?

Thanks,
krisy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FusionCharts provides a product named [FusionCharts Free](http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/).

FusionCharts Free is dual licensed under the MIT (X11) and GNU GPL licenses.

In a nutshell, the above licenses allow you to:

- Use the software for any purpose, commercial or personal
- Modify the software's source code to suit your needs
- Share the software with your friends and neighbors
- Re-distribute the software as part of your software or hardware
  applications

Read more about the licensing part here - http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/product-licensing/

Comment: Fusion charts looks really great, but - with the free edition - you can't export charts (see "option to export charts"): http://www.fusioncharts.com/goodies/fusioncharts-free/compare/